# Pushing to public repo from private repo failed with status code 403

Tags: github-actions

I have 2 repos: user/ext-private and user/ext-public. I want to push some files to public repo but its failing with following error:

```
[master 869955c] update it
 1 file changed, 1 insertion(+), 1 deletion(-)
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
remote: Permission to user/ext-public.git denied to github-actions[bot].
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/user/ext-public/': The requested URL returned error: 403
Error: Process completed with exit code 128.
```

Here is my action:

```
name: Master Branch

on:
  push:
    branches: [ master ]

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Use Node.js 14.x
      uses: actions/setup-node@v2
      with:
        node-version: 14.x
        cache: 'yarn'
    - run: yarn    

    - name: Checkout Public repo
      uses: actions/checkout@v2
      with:
        repository: user/ext-public
        path: ext-public
        ref: 'master'
        token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
        fetch-depth: 0

    - name: Update file
      run: |
        git config -l
        echo "Hello you!" >> README.md
        git config --global user.name 'GithubUser'
        git config --global user.email 'MYActions@users.noreply.github.com'
        git add .
        git commit -m "update it"
        git status
        git push -u origin HEAD
      working-directory: ext-public
```

See the error log here
https://github.com/coure2011/ext_code/runs/5548688844?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: As the message states, it seems related to the scope permission. The github bot doesn't seem to be allowed to push to this public repository. You may need to use a PAT or allow the bot to push code directly to master on the public repo for this push to work. You could also use [an action from the marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=commit+push+) to perform the push operation for you.

Comment: I created repository secrets for both private and public branches for both Actions and Dependabot but still no luck.

Comment: Did you try using an action to commit push the updated code with a PAT? (I can suggest to use [this one](https://github.com/GuillaumeFalourd/git-commit-push) as it is the one I maintain, but it's not the only option). If I'm not mistaken, the PAT is mandatory to push to another repo.

Comment: Used GuillaumeFalourd/git-commit-push@v1.3 but still the same error. Btw! I am using free github account not sure maybe that is the issue.

Comment: created two public repo for demo and here is the error: https://github.com/coure2011/ext_code/runs/5548688844?check_suite_focus=true

Comment: It seems to me the problem is that you're using the GITHUB_TOKEN (which has a specific permission scope) instead of a PAT (Personal Access Token). You can't push to another repo using the GITHUB_TOKEN. You need a PAT to do so.

Comment: Yeah issue was of the Token

Comment: Great, I'll add it as official answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're using the GITHUB_TOKEN (which has a [specific permission scope](https://github.blog/changelog/2021-04-20-github-actions-control-permissions-for-github_token/)) instead of a PAT ([Personal Access Token](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token)).

**You can't push to another repo using the GITHUB_TOKEN**, you'll need a PAT to do so.

There are also many [actions from the marketplace](https://github.com/marketplace?type=actions&query=commit+push+) to perform the push operation for you, after adding the PAT as a secret.

Comment: This seems to be a known bug. See https://github.com/github/docs/issues/21156